# bash_profile configure confusion

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to install Python virtual environment using STEP:5 in this link [Install OpenCV 3 on macOS with Homebrew (the easy way)](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/)

I am having trouble in configuring this file properly

```
$ nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Only editing the bash_profile like show

```
# Virtualenv/VirtualenvWrapper
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Is not allowing me to goto next step

I got this Warning `mkvirtualenv: command not found`

So altered it using help with this `techstricks.com/mkvirtualenv-command-not-found-virtualenvwrapper/`

Found this link on how to virtualenwrapper
 `virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#python-interpreter-virtualenv-and-path`

My `bash_profile` contains

```
    #Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

# Virtualenv/VirtualenvWrapper
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'
```

When I try to `$ source ~/.bash_profile`

I'm getting this

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

How do I fix this???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working.

I installed Virtualenv and Wrapper separatley

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Might help someone in future.

---

I installed Virtual Enviornment Wrapper using

```
pip install --user virtualenvwrapper
```

Link

> virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#python-interpreter-virtualenv-and-path

Content of my bash_profile file

> ## Homebrew
>
> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
>
> #export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
>
> # Virtualenv/VirtualenvWrapper
>      source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
>      #export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
>      #export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
>      #export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
>      #export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'

Content of my bashrc file

> export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
>
> export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/projects
>
> source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue, but the way I got around it was different than /u/Santhosh DC. Following the breaking changes in Homebrew sometime in the last two months, I had to change:
    `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python`
to
    `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2`.

Hope this helps someone.